# Outputting with LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, csv

I wrote some code that combines two different files onto one file and then it compares the data from the matching seqNum and does a little math equation on them. The problem I am having is printing out all of the other match data with each seqNum with the answer I got from the from the math part. I used LINQ to match the two different seqNum arrays and then wrote a while loop to print out all the data. When every I put an int value on the variable "item"(the answer from the math equation) I get an Out of Bounds Exception, but when I don't put an int value on "item" it loops and outputs the same answer for every item I have in the array then moves on to the next answer and does the same thing. Here's the code...

```
    private void executeBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //NET OIL VARIANCE MATHEMATICS
        if (netOilRadBtn.Checked)
        {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter("testNetOil.csv"))
            {
                var items = netOil.Zip(seqNum, (oil, seq) => new { Oil = oil, Seq = seq });
                var items2 = netOil2.Zip(seqNum2, (oil, seq) => new { Oil = oil, Seq = seq });
                sw.WriteLine("Lease Name, Field Name, Reservoir, Operator, County, ST, Majo, Resv Cat, Discount Rate, Net Oil Interest, Net Gas Interest, Working Interest, Gross Wells, Ultimate Oil, Ultimate Gas, Gross Oil, Gross NGL, Gross Gas, Net Oil, Net Gas, Net NGL, Revenue To Int., Oper. Expense, Total Invest., Revenue Oil, Revenue Gas, Operating Profit, Revenue NGL, Disc Net Income, SEQ, Well ID, INC ASN, Life Years, Own Qual, Production Tax, NET OIL VARIANCE");

                foreach (var item in items.Join(items2, i => i.Seq, i => i.Seq, (a, b) =>
                {
                    double first = Convert.ToDouble(a.Oil);
                    double second = Convert.ToDouble(b.Oil);
                    double answer = (first - second) / second;
                    return string.Format("{0}, {1}", a.Seq, answer);
                }))
                {                        
                    int x = listHead;
                    while (x != -1)
                    {
                        sw.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}, {12}, {13}, {14}, {15}, {16}, {17}, {18}, {19}, {20}, {21}, {22}, {23}, {24}, {25}, {26}, {27}, {28}, {29}, {30}, {31}, {32}, {33}, {34}, {35}",
                QuoteString(leaseName[x]), fieldName[x], QuoteString2(reservoir[x]), operator1[x], county[x], state[x], majo[x], resvCatgory[x], disRate[x], netOil2Int[x], netGas2Int[x], workingInt[x], grossWells[x]
                , ultOil[x], ultGas[x], grossOil[x], grossNGL[x], grossGas[x], netOil[x], netGas[x], netNGL[x], revToInt[x], operExpense[x], totInvest[x], revOil[x], revGas[x], operatingProfit[x],
                revNGL[x], discNetIncome[x], seqNum[x], wellID[x], incASN[x], lifeYears[x], ownQual[x], prodTax[x], item[x]);
                x = pointers[x];

                        //sw.WriteLine(item);
                    }
                    sw.Close();
                }
            }
        }
```

I was just wondering if anyone could help me with this problem and just have the answer outputting to the correct seqNum with all the other matching data arrays. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand two things. First, item is always a string as far as I can see. Second, why do you write one character from item: `item[x]`? Or should that be `item` (without indexer)?

Comment: @GertArnold return string.Format should make item a string, item should be without the indexer but I want to match it with the matching data that I have with the seqNum arrays

Comment: @GertArnold The loop is printing out about 79,000 lines of output for some reason, it goes through all my data and add the first answer, then goes through all the data again and adds the second answer and so on...

Comment: Too many unknowns. If you are getting a OutOfBounds exception, it probably means x is outside the size of one of the arrays. But x is initialized to listHead , it is changed by the contents of the pointers array and you haven't said what either of them are. You should start by looking at the value of x when the exception is thrown and then backtrack from there to see where it gets that value.

Answer (score 0):

OK, first off I moved the calculation logic into a method to make this a bit clearer, so you'll need to add this:

```
private double GetTheAnswer(double first, double second)
{
    double answer = (first - second) / second;
    return answer;
}
```

Then I modified your LINQ statement and selected the bits you're interested in into an anonymous object. After that I added 1 more field on the end of your output write statement and then accessed the properties that I defined against the anonymous type. Also I removed the array index '[x]' against item:

```
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter("testNetOil.csv"))
        {
            var items = netOil.Zip(seqNum, (oil, seq) => new { Oil = oil, Seq = seq });
            var items2 = netOil2.Zip(seqNum2, (oil, seq) => new { Oil = oil, Seq = seq });
            sw.WriteLine("Lease Name, Field Name, Reservoir, Operator, County, ST, Majo, Resv Cat, Discount Rate, Net Oil Interest, Net Gas Interest, Working Interest, Gross Wells, Ultimate Oil, Ultimate Gas, Gross Oil, Gross NGL, Gross Gas, Net Oil, Net Gas, Net NGL, Revenue To Int., Oper. Expense, Total Invest., Revenue Oil, Revenue Gas, Operating Profit, Revenue NGL, Disc Net Income, SEQ, Well ID, INC ASN, Life Years, Own Qual, Production Tax, NET OIL VARIANCE");

            foreach (var item in items.Join(items2, i => i.Seq, i => i.Seq, (a, b) => new { SeqID = a.Seq, Answer = this.GetTheAnswer(Convert.ToDouble(a.Oil), Convert.ToDouble(b.Oil)) }))
            {                        
                int x = listHead;
                while (x != -1)
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("{0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4}, {5}, {6}, {7}, {8}, {9}, {10}, {11}, {12}, {13}, {14}, {15}, {16}, {17}, {18}, {19}, {20}, {21}, {22}, {23}, {24}, {25}, {26}, {27}, {28}, {29}, {30}, {31}, {32}, {33}, {34}, {35}, {36}",
            QuoteString(leaseName[x]), fieldName[x], QuoteString2(reservoir[x]), operator1[x], county[x], state[x], majo[x], resvCatgory[x], disRate[x], netOil2Int[x], netGas2Int[x], workingInt[x], grossWells[x]
            , ultOil[x], ultGas[x], grossOil[x], grossNGL[x], grossGas[x], netOil[x], netGas[x], netNGL[x], revToInt[x], operExpense[x], totInvest[x], revOil[x], revGas[x], operatingProfit[x],
            revNGL[x], discNetIncome[x], seqNum[x], wellID[x], incASN[x], lifeYears[x], ownQual[x], prodTax[x], item.SeqID, item.Answer);
            x = pointers[x];

                    //sw.WriteLine(item);
                }
                sw.Close();
            }
        }
```

Obviously I couldn't test this for you but hopefully this will send you down the right path and I got the right end of the stick!

Comment: Thanks for the help, but this still does the same thing.

Comment: I think the issue is in your while loop then. It doesn't have anything in it that will change, so each iteration of the for loop you're going to go through the whole list and output it. It's hard to comment without seeing the whole thing but should you be using item.SeqID instead of x and not looping?

Comment: I've tried using SeqID instead of x for the loop but it says that it does not exist in the current context.

Comment: Also, item.SeqID is a string so I would not be able to use that as an indexer.